# System Volume too low on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, sound, realtek, 18.04

I am on my way to completely shifting from Windows 10 to Ubuntu. So I dual booted the latest `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`. After doing so I realized that my laptop's volume is too low. In Windows 10, the volume would be loud enough to fill an empty room, but in Ubuntu, I've to put my ears to the speaker to listen, even after having the volume to full maximum. Some articles suggested that I check out *alsamixer*, but that too wasn't of much help.

I then realized that I might have to install the drivers. Now here's the problem, on Windows, my audio driver shows as **Realtek HD Audio**  whereas in Linux it shows **Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio**. I know for sure that my audio drivers are from Realtek because even HP's support website says so. I even have the Realtek HD Audio Manager in windows. I don't want to mess up my system trying to install any wrong driver.

Please help me, I've been struggling with this for days now:

```
rdias002@rdias002:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 129
Memory at b1228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at b1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

I tried searching for solutions but couldn't really find one that fits my problem. I almost gave up, but then thought of asking for help here. Please excuse me if my question seems noobish, as this is my first time. I am a Windows power user so I'm familiar with computers and the command line, but quite a beginner to Linux.

So how can I get the Windows like volume in Ubuntu?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Laptop: **`HP 15 bs-544-tu`**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As a temporary solution, you can manually set it higher than 100% from the command line with:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 150%
```

If the command is not found, you need to install:

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-utils
```

The 0 there is the index of the sound card sink you want to use. You can determine it with:

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index'
```

The 150% is the percentage of volume you want. Start with 150% and work from there slowly. You dont want to blow your laptop speakers with clipped audio

Comment: thanks a ton. it did as you said. I don't want to be ungrateful, but I am **not** very happy with the audio quality. There's a lot of noise. Is there anyway I can get clean and loud audio? Or is this the only method? Once again thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: This works on Linux mint 19 also. Great solution

Comment: Audio quality is going to be bad above 100%, because the signal gets clipped, causing distortion.

Comment: +1 for showing how to find the index of the sound card sink

Comment: Worked for me - my audio drivers were fine, but full volume was just not quite loud enough for the music I like to listen to on headphones.  Now it is - thanks!

Comment: BTW does this need to be added to an export to be done on startup, or does it "stick" after a reboot?

Comment: Note that after doing this, I used my keyboard to move volume down and up and it undid the 150% thing. Turning on Ubuntu's "Over-amplification" setting (as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130967/847577)) allowed the change to actually stick.

Comment: @tscizzle This answer is for a version of ubuntu desktop where there was no overamplification setting. The packages have since been updated and allow yout to make the setting normally now.

Comment: Only this works on Linux Mint 20.0.2 for WH-XB-900N

Answer (score 4):

Unverified, because I don't have the hardware anymore.

Most RealTek audio chips have a dedicated headphone amplifier that needs to be enabled if you want to connect headphones to it. By default, it is bypassed, as it introduces a bit of noise, and the amplifier is unnecessary if you connect another amplifier anyway.

In the ALSA sound system, there would be a switch in `alsamixer` for the amplifier, shown as a mixer channel with no slider, just a mute button, and pressing `m` to mute/unmute would activate and deactivate the amplifier.

In PulseAudio, I would expect this to show up in `pavucontrol`, either as a separate port (so it can be selected on the "Output Devices" tab), or as a device profile (which you would select on the "Configuration" tab).

Comment: `pavucontrol` has solved my problem.

Comment: Oh yes! In Ubuntu Volume Control GUI you have to select Port:" Headphones (unplugged)" instead of "Line Out(plugged in)" and kaboom - it works loud. Thank you so much!
(ALC1220 on X299 Aorus Gaming 7)

Comment: I meant pavucontrol helps. Going to regular volume control will break it again.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the option in:

`Settings -> Sound -> Over-Amplification -> ON`

if you want a higher volume **beyond 100%**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: No souch option *Over-Amplification* below *Output volume* for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in that the master sound of alsamixer is set to low.
To get loud and clear sound you need to type `alsamixer` in terminal. And using arrow keys set master sound to max value.

Comment: That's naive and old experience. Specifically in 18.04 at 100% master volume still results in low sound

Comment: It worked for me on several computers and for a couple of my mates

Answer (score 0):

Selecting *Settings* then *Sound* and turning on *Over Amplification* solves the problem.

Comment: No souch option *Over-Amplification* below *Output volume* for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in "Settings" GUI *permanently* solved the problem on my laptop. Using "Settings" -> "Sound" -> "Over-Amplification" to set that parameter to "ON" provides a fixed overamplification percentage of around 30%. This way has the advantage that the fix persists indefinitely, even after you close "Settings" and subsequently use the desktop's built-in audio playback volume slider.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback: edited to conform to community guidelines. Shunz's boilerplate reply that this doesn't answer the OP's question is mistaken; perhaps more clear in "as (now) edited" reply.

Comment: No souch option *Over-Amplification* below *Output volume* for me on Ubuntu 18.04.