# Low sound on xubuntu 18.04 (better than no sound of other distros I tried)

Tags: 18.04, sound, xubuntu

I have got xubuntu 18.04 on old Toshiba Satellite M115-S1061 notebook.
The sound was great with WinXP, so no hardware problem.
I tried Lubuntu 16.04, Lubuntu 18.04 and Linux Mint Mate19.3. All with "no sound problem".

Now xubuntu 18.04 has at least some very very low sound in headphones. Alsamixer unmuted, Pavucontrol on maximum. 
Plese, have you got some hint for me?

I hope you are ok and enjoying your quarantine.
 Josef

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, it's a fantastic 14 years old laptop, could you give us the output of `pactl list sinks` for the clue.

Comment: ![pic](https://ibb.co/WGXbNc3).<br/> module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
  device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
 Porty:
  analog-output-headphones: Analogová sluchátka (priority: 9000)
 Aktivní port: analog-output-headphones
 Formáty:
  pcm

Comment: Please edit your question and copy and paste the output.

Answer (score 0):

Citation from [Low sound volume with headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123910/low-sound-volume-with-headphones?rq=1) and [System volume too low on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028968/system-volume-too-low-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Open Alsamixer and set speaker volume to zero.

[image: Alsamixer]

However this doesn't resolve your problem then,

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 200%
```

Comment: I have got under alsamixer only Master/PCM/Mic/... so first advice is not applicable. I tried the second - pactl... now it is a little bit louder, but the sound is full of noise and buzz.

Comment: That tells us the audio card is not properly recognized or configured at this moment.